# How to remotely recycle an application pool of IIS 8.5?

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

Can I remotely recycle a certain application pool of IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2?

I want to trigger this when logged onto another computer running Windows 7 with a domain user account that is in the admin group of the remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that could work would be to download and install a Utility called PSExec - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649

Copy contents to a folder on the Compuer you log onto and add the **PSExec command to that users login script**.

```
Psexec.exe \\{IIS8server} "appcmd recycle apppool app_pool_name"
```

Answer (score 2):

To execute commands remotely, you'd normally wrap them in a powershell [`Invoke-Command`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) command with the `-ComputerName` parameter.

So you could wrap the `appcmd` command in an `Invoke-Command` command.

There is a [native IIS powershell snapin](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/powershell), but I'm not a big fan of it. It's a bit clunky to use and to get working reliably (and its another dependancy you need to maintain. `Invoke-Command` works on pretty much anything that has `winrm` configured).